# Should we merge "notications" and "push-notifications" tags?

Tags: discussion

I've just created the tag [push-notifications](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/push-notifications) since I didn't any push related tag to make a question.

After that I have discovered the tag [notifications](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notifications) that says:

> An action of notifying something from an App or Game installed in
>   phone.

In my understand those are two different things.

**Notifications**: that litle bar that appear when an app want to call your atention like make a checkin, ask you to drink water and something like this. They just works with background tasks enabled or when the app is in the foreground.

**Push-Notifications**: Notifications received from a server to do something in the app, like a comment in *Facebook* or a new article in *WPAlerts*.

Should we merge then? Or perhaps in some places notifications were incorrectly used?

Answer (score 2):

I think they are two very different things and should not be merged.